# Are new hiking trails and mountain roads still being developed?

Tags: hiking

I live in Seattle and all the hiking trails and scenic roads that I know of are all decades old. I haven’t heard of any new investments into making the nature more accessible but perhaps I’m just not we’ll versed in local developments.

Is all outdoors infrastructure development currently on pause, at least in the US? If not, where can I learn of new mountain roads and hiking trails/campsites?

Comment: For one, [making new trails takes a lot of planning and effort to do properly](https://www.americantrails.org/images/documents/Nature-Trail-Development.pdf) so I wouldn’t expect new trails to be constantly popping up. Plus, there’s a balance to be struck to not impact the environment overmuch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are definitely new trails being cut in your area.

In general, you should check the Washington Trails Association website to find this kind of information: https://www.wta.org/

You can see some of the projects underway, and even get involved, by visiting the [Find a Work Party](https://www.wta.org/volunteer/schedule) page.  A few of the new trails listed there include

- [Mount Spokane - Trail 183](https://www.wta.org/volunteer/schedule/workparty/a2m2K00000AVeUh/)
- [Yacolt Burn State Forest - Sword Fern Trail](https://www.wta.org/volunteer/schedule/workparty/a2m2K00000AVfJk/)
- [Frog Mountain](https://www.wta.org/volunteer/schedule/workparty/a2m2K00000AVcqt/)

As you would expect, a lot of those work parties are for maintenance work on existing trails.

Comment: Thanks! Time to go work on a trail I guess :)